# Swift: 'if' statement with a equals to b or c

Tags: swift

If I want to make sure that variable A is equal to B or C in Swift, I would normally write something like:

```
if a == b || a == c {
   //Do Something
}
```

However, I wonder if there is a shorthand version of this statement in Swift to simplify with something like:

```
if a == (b || c) {
   //Do Something
}
```

Is there such a thing in Swift?

Comment: Maybe `[b, c].contains(a)`?

Comment: let a = 1
        let b = 1
        let c = 1
        if a == b,a==c  {
            print("all of them are equal")
        }else {
            print("not equal")
        }

Comment: @AnkitKushwah Not what OP asked. OP wants to not if one of them are equal to a

Comment: @LeoDabus no i dont think so there is another way

Comment: Upvoted, because well, it's opinionated. In my world - IT since Fortran & COBOL 74 since 1976 - why do anything **but** `if a == b || a == c`? (Yes, again, opinionated.) It should compile to basically the same thing (size, build, whatever). Yet how better can you express "A" **isn't** "B" or "C"? Sure, Swift is a *fantastic* language - again my "opinion" - but still? In terms of something that means something that means the *same* thing to everyone, regardless of language or age? I vote for what you have. It's something we *all* understand clearly and can easily translate across any language.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is a switch case:

```
let a = 1
let b = 2
let c = 1

switch a {
case b, c:
    print("it was equal to one of them")
default: break
}
```

This seems heavy-handed when there are only two tests (equality to b or c), because you could have written it out as in your first example. But it comes in mighty useful where you have multiple tests (cases) each consisting of multiple equality comparisons.

Comment: Just made a comment that addresses - I hope - others coming from someplace other than pure Swift. While this doesn't really answer a total of three variables (`A != B & C`) it's intriguing. Do you think it's more "expressive" than code for four or more variables?(Hopefully asked with respect. Again Matt, I posted my comment before reading your answer.)

Comment: @dfd I have no opinion about "expressive" and I don't think the notion is a good fit for Stack Overflow. Modern languages try to save us from the error-prone use of repeated `and` and `or` comparisons. A Swift array has `contains` or `index` for multiple `or`, and `allSatisfy` for multiple `and`, and those are the Swifty way. My answer presents an alternative for `or` that I use under certain circumstances (which I described in the answer).